# How to use Backbone.StateManager?

Tags: backbone.js, state-machine

I am trying to explore Backbone.StateManager but couldn't find much material on this. 
I have gone through [the documentation](https://github.com/crashlytics/backbone.statemanager) but there is no simple example of using it.

I have made an example like this

```
(function($) {

    var UserInputView  = Backbone.View.extend({
        states: {
            foo: {
                enter: function () {
                    alert('hi');
                    return console.log('enter bar');
                },
                exit: function () {
                    alert('hi');
                    return console.log('exit foo');
                },
                transitions: {
                    transitions: {
                        'onBeforeExitTo:anotherState': function () {
                            alert('hi');
                        },
                        'onExitTo:anotherState': function () {
                            alert('hi');
                        },
                        'onBeforeEnterFrom:anotherState': function () {
                            alert('hi');
                        },
                        'onEnterFrom:anotherState': function () {
                            alert('hi');
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            bar: {
                enter: function () {
                    alert('hi');
                    return console.log('enter bar');
                },
                exit: function () {
                    alert('hi');
                    return console.log('exit bar');
                },

            }
        },
        initialize: function () {
            var statemanager;

            alert('intialized');
            console.log(this.states);
            statemanager = Backbone.StateManager.addStateManager(this.states);

            return statemanager;
        },
        render: function () {

            alert('render');
        }
    });
    var user = new UserInputView();

})(jQuery);
```

In all this code only intialization function is working. Rest of the code is not functioning. Please guide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, your code misses a state change and a correct target for `Backbone.StateManager.addStateManager`. As stated in the documentation, to use [Backbone.StateManager with objects](https://github.com/crashlytics/backbone.statemanager#using-with-objects)

> StateManager provides an easy method to painlessly add a StateManager
>   to any object. `StateManager.addStateManager` takes a target object and
>   an optional set of options, reads in any states defined on the target,
>   and creates a new StateManager. It also sets a number of methods on
>   target, including `triggerState`, `getCurrentState`, and a reference to
>   the StateManager at `target.stateManager`.

which means that the target for `Backbone.StateManager.addStateManager` should be your object instance and that you can start changing state with `model.triggerState`. For example :

```
var UserInputView  = Backbone.View.extend({
    states: {
        // your states
    },
    initialize: function () {
        var statemanager;
        statemanager = Backbone.StateManager.addStateManager(this);
    }
});

var user = new UserInputView();
user.triggerState('foo');
```

A demo based on your code, to [visualize some state manipulations](http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/39qXv/)